# Convert Action<T> callback to an await

Tags: c#, action, async-await

I have a method that takes a `Action<String>`. When the method finishes its processing it calls the `Action<String>` with the return value.

```
MethodWithCallback((finalResponse)=> {
   Console.WriteLine(finalResponse);
});
```

I want to use this in a web.api async controller. How do I wrap this method so I can `await` for this method to complete in an `async` manner. I cannot modify the method itself, it is in a legacy code base.

What I would like to be able to do is this

```
String returnValue = await MyWrapperMethodThatCallsMethodWithCallback();
```

Comment: I would consider modifying the method itself; with its current design, it has no way to report errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can leverage the [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) class and solve the problem in a generic way:

```
Task<T> AsAsync<T>(Action<Action<T>> target) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    try {
        target(t => tcs.SetResult(t));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        tcs.SetException(ex);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

That way you don't have to modify your `MethodWhitCallback`:

```
var result = await AsAsync<string>(MethodWithCallback);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Your code is somewhat confusing, because under normal circumstances, `Main()` can't be `async`. Also, you should avoid `async void` methods as much as possible.

Comment: Tnx, I edited it. The code was copied from linqpad, where Main has to have the async keyword in order to use the await keyword in it...