# Asynchronous web service request in Xamarin Forms using a corporate library that uses callbacks

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, async-await

Today, I have a specific question for a specific scenario.

### Scenario:

- I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application and I´m using
  PRISM(obviously MVVM too).
- I have certain restrictions about requesting a web service. One of
  them is: I have to use a corporate(and internal) library because of security and politics in my work
  .
- This corporate library exposes the methods for requesting web
  services using callbacks. One of them looks like this:

  ```
  public void Post(string requestUriString, string data,
                   System.Action callbackSuccess, System.Action callbackError);
  ```
- I mean, this library doesn´t expose async methods, as HttpClient, for
  example. Instead of that, this library uses a callback aproach.
- The corporate library have different implementations for android and
  ios(one library for each one platform). And because of this, I need to use dependency injection to use the platform specific code

### My question is

Which is the best way to implement this library(**talking about performance and best practices**) and why? 
The main question is about to explain why one solution could be the better vs others,  and give an example(code).

I was thinking in the examples below but I don´t know which one could be the better or if the combination of one of them could be better, or ... none of them.

1. Calling the library directly from the ViewModel and using the callbacks:
   [Using callbacks example](https://gist.github.com/jorge-tinoco/03c3ef9cc2db11fa45a8f52a1e824748)
2. Using the System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run as the wrapper from the UI thread(directly from the ViewModel)
   [Using Task.Run example](https://gist.github.com/jorge-tinoco/9de57691bf4f0df9df830037279bff3c)
3. Create a separate class that only contains the web service request and also use the callbacks as an asynchronus method.
   [Separate business + callbacks example](https://gist.github.com/jorge-tinoco/67de87db9db8566542fa177fa2b3fd7c)

Comment: A standard way would be to use a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Action<T> callback to an await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830601/convert-actiont-callback-to-an-await)

Comment: Thank you for your comments @JSteward . All the possible solutions that I gave in my question, actually works. My main concern is about why which one of them is not the best solution or why is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a task completion source.

```
public static class XXXExtensions
{
    public static Task PostAsync(this XXX self, string requestUriString, string data)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        self.Post(
           requestUriString,
           data,
           () => tcs.TrySetResult(true)
           () => tcs.TrySetException(new Exception()));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
await xxx.PostAsync(requestUriString, data);
```

Comment: Hi @Paulo Morgado, thanks for your example. About your solution, why would you prefer this solution vs for example simply use the callbacks (without using a task)? I have an  [example](https://gist.github.com/jorge-tinoco/03c3ef9cc2db11fa45a8f52a1e824748) about just using the callbacks without Task/await/async

Comment: another question about your solution is: should I make the request directly in my ViewModel or would you use a different layer for all the webservice request as in [this example](https://gist.github.com/jorge-tinoco/67de87db9db8566542fa177fa2b3fd7c)?

Comment: `async-await` uses the synchronization context to ensure you're back to the main thread. It's how modern .NET works.

Comment: Once you go async, you must go async all the way. You'll have an async call in the view model.