# Can I pass the return value of a child action to the view in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to figure out how I can pass my returned value to the view without any exceptions.

I'm having hard time passing my bool value due to it's async to my view model.

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public async Task<bool> ValidateCurrentUser()
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ticketKey"].ToString()))
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    string ticket = Session["ticketKey"].ToString();
                    result = await _authenticationService.ValidateUser(ticket);
                    if (result)
                        return result;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return result;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Razor page

```
 @{
      bool isvalid = string.Equals(Html.Action("ValidateCurrentUser", "Authentication").ToString(), true);
                            if (isvalid)
                            {
                                <div>
                                   RED
                                </div>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div>
                                   BLUE
                                </div>
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What do you use ? net or net core?

Comment: This is .netframework 4.7.2 @Serge

Answer (score 0):

Use TaskCompletionSource() if you are having problems with the order of execution and things not happening synchronously.

[Convert Action<T> callback to an await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830601/convert-actiont-callback-to-an-await)

Comment: I think the problem is more of Razor not supporting Action requests that are async.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: InvalidOperationException: HttpServerUtility.Execute

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public async Task<bool> ValidateCurrentUser()
        {
            return await IsUserValid();
        }

        private async Task<bool> IsUserValid()
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ticketKey"].ToString())))
                {
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    string ticket = Session["ticketKey"].ToString());
                    result = await _authenticationService.ValidateUser(ticket);
                    if (result)
                        return result;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return result;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: How will this make any difference? The index function is  just calling on a private method with async. @Aniki

This will just give me - InvalidOperationException: HttpServerUtility.Execute